# If I use python to run a system command, and want to get it's dynamic result, what should i do?

Tags: python, subprocess

```
@staticmethod
    def execute_cmd(cmd):
        exitcode, output = subprocess.getstatusoutput(cmd)
        if exitcode != 0:
            MyLog.error(f'{cmd} executes failed!')
            raise Exception(f'{cmd} executes failed!')

        return output
```

the return output can not get the dynamic result.
eg: if i execute the command "git clone xxx" by using this method, it cannot show all the information the "git clone xxx" shows on the stdout.

Comment: What is a "dynamic result"? Can you give an example where this doesn't work?

Comment: Use subprocess.run with capture_output=True

Comment: @AKX the question has changed, you can see it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import subprocess


ressult = subprocess.check_output("echo 'hello'", shell=True)
print(ressult)

#Output:
#b'hello\n'
```

Comment: thank a lot. what  kind of type in python does the result belongs?

Comment: check_output() returns bytes, if you want to work with a string you have to convert it like this: ressult.decode("utf-8")